# Regex that Match the last digit if it's alone

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a string like so:

```
11547778:115,12
```

My question is, is there an expression that match the last number if it is made of a single digit then use the $.replace() function to put a 0 in front of it
for exemple:

```
84500015:217,8 will become-> 84500015:217,08
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you can look for a string which specifically ends with a comma and a single number, something like this:

```js
['11547778:115,12', '19038940:123,a', '84500015:217,8'].forEach(function(val) {
  var foo = val.replace(/,(\d)$/, ',0$1');
  console.log(foo);
});
```

Comment: `{1}` is redundant as this is default behaviour. +1 though, this works.

Comment: @ctwheels thanks, I was messing around and forgot to remove that :)

Comment: Of course, by using a capturing group. Thank you so much @RoryMcCrossan simple and perfect!

Comment: @Richard no problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
"11547778:115,2".replace(/,([0-9])$/g,',0$1') -> "11547778:115,02"
"11547778:115,12".replace(/,([0-9])$/g,',0$1') -> "11547778:115,12"
```

Comment: That is a valid answer too, but \d is more elegant ;)

Answer (score 1):

Non-RE approach

```
if (str.substr(-2, 1) == ",") 
    str = str.replace(",", ",0");
```